# Invalid Formula Does not throw Error - VBA Excel 2010 64 bit

Tags: excel, 32bit-64bit, vba

I have this project that works fine with Excel 32 bit but I am having problems running it in 64 bit.

I have this part where I handle Invalid formulas (those things that could not be evaluated by excel.) 32 bit used to throw error that I could catch but in 64 bit, I seem to have Issues that I am not sure of. The code kinda got stucked.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim x As Variant
    On Error Goto ErrH:
    ReDim x(1, 1)
    x(0, 0) = "=1+1"
    x(0, 1) = "=1+ "  ' <--this is a sample of what I refer to as Invalid formula
    x(1, 0) = "=1+2"
    x(1, 1) = "=1+1"


    Range("A1:B2").Value = x  ' <--Im stuck in this part. 
                              ' the program does not proceed beyond this point 
                              ' and does not throw error like it used to.

    'I do something here


    On Error Goto 0
   Exit Sub

ErrH:


    ' I have bunch of stuffs that I do here, basically, Error handling.


End Sub
```

What do I need to do for Excel to throw an error on the line that I have indicated in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way for this to work for me.
I just used Range.FormulaArray instead of Range.Value although I'm not yet sure what is the difference between the two, It seems to work just fine.

But I still don't know why excel 64 bit doesn't throw the error that It used to.maybe I'll look into it next time that I have time.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the formula, you can use the predifined function in VBA

```
Right(text,number of character)
ISNUMBER(text)
```

dim i as integer :i=0
    dim j as integer :j=0

```
for i = 0 to 1
    for j = 0 to 1
        if ISNUMBER(Right(x(i,j),1)) OR Right(x(i,j),1)=")" Then
        ' do anything you want if the formula is correct
        else
            Goto ErrH:
        End If
    next
next
```

I don't think you can output the value of X by using this method as X is a 2-D array.

```
Range("A1:B2").Value = x
```

The proper way to output it is use 2 for loop

```
dim i as integer :i=0
dim j as integer :j=0

for i = 0 to 1
    for j = 0 to 1
    Cells(i+1).value = x(i,j)
    next
next
```

The error handling there you may output a message

```
ErrH:
  MsgBox "Invalid Formula"
  exit sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I can't use this for 2 reasons, 1st, your suggestion is only limited to formulas like the ones I have given. Our code uses more complex excel formula functions such as AVERAGE,COUNT,IF and the likes and we also use named ranges. 2nd, It will take time to process what we do, we usually process more than 65k rows and around 500 columns, looping through cells will consume time. I guarantee that displaying 2D the way I did doesn't cause problems before we migrated to 64 bit office. I  just want to know why 64 bit excel doesn't throw an error the way It used to